# How to extract a specific URL segment with Regex & C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have that kind of URLs:

/domain.com/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7/filename.ext

Sometimes

http://someother.com/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7/filename.ext

I need to extract segment 6 specifically with C# and Regex. Regex is an absolute requirement as I might want to extract segment 3 in the future just by changing some configuration.

Comment: .Net has a `Uri` class designed specifically for parsing out URIs.  Regular Expressions don't strike me as the right tool for this job.

Comment: "Regex is an absolute requirement as I might want to extract segment 3 in the future just by changing some configuration." I'd argue that you can do that with almost any extraction method (e.g. string.Split)

Comment: Or if you want a C# solution, if that's the case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tSWDO6. Also note that you can put the regex in your configuration as per your need.

Comment: `new Uri(...).LocalPath.Split('/')[6]` is far more reliable than Regex.

Comment: My requirement was C# + Regex. Regex was an absolute requirement. Uri would work in a fixed context. I'm not in such context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you should preferably go for URL related classes for parsing a URL as explained in another answer, as builtin functions are proven and well tested for handling even the corner cases, but as you mentioned you have some limitation and can only use a regex solution, you can try with following solution.

Finding sixth or Nth segment can be easily done using this regex,

```
(?:([^/]+)/){7}
```

which captures 6+1 (N+1 in general for Nth segment where +1 is for matching domain part of URL) segments and the group retains the last captured value which can be accessed using group1.

Here, `([^/]+)` matches one or more any characters except a `/` and captures the content in group1 followed by `/` and whole of it matching exactly 7 times.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV7ID3/1)**

[C# code demo](https://rextester.com/JNT81899)

```
var pattern = "(?:([^/]+)/){7}";
var match = Regex.Match("/domain.com/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7/filename.ext", pattern);
Console.WriteLine("Segment: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
match = Regex.Match("http://someother.com/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5/segment6/segment7/filename.ext", pattern);
Console.WriteLine("Segment: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Prints the value of sixth segment,

```
Segment: segment6
Segment: segment6
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I couldn't use Uri class. That's why I specified that Regex was an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 2):

.NET has the class `UriTemplate` (Amy mentioned `Uri`in the comments already). There are a lot of aspects on matching URLs (like case-sensitivity, traling slash vs no-trailing-slash etc.), that can make the task of [finding a suitable regular expression](https://xkcd.com/1171/) overly complex.

UriTemplate can deal with a lot of those things out-of-the-box. Maybe you can use that for a divide-and-conquer-like approach.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://someother.com");
UriTemplate template 
    = new UriTemplate("segment1}/{segment2}/{segment3}/{segment4}/{segment5}/{segment6}/{segment7}/{filename}");
Uri fullUri 
    = new Uri("http://someother.com/super1/kali2/fragi3/listig4/expi5/ali6/docious7/filename.ext");

UriTemplateMatch results = template.Match(baseUri, fullUri);

if(results.BoundVariables["segment6"]) {
    WriteLine(results.BoundVariables["segment6"]);
    // Output: "ali6"
    // further regex matching can take place here
}
```

Have a look at the [.NET reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uritemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?<=\.com)(?:\/([^\/]+))+\/[^\/.]+?\.\w+`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ipdtVg/1)

[C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9CVBwS)